# Batch: set second word in sentance set /p

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've a question:

So i've a script:

```
set /p "variableA"="Enter a Sentence: "
*Some script I don't know*
echo "%second word of sentence%"
```

How can I echo the second word of the inputted sentence?

Comment: Use the FOR command with the /F option to read the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon the content of your sentence, you may also be able to set each word to a separate variable; something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "sentence="
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set word[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="

:Loop
Set /P "sentence=Enter a sentence: "
If Not Defined sentence GoTo Loop
Set "i=1"
Set "word[!i!]=%sentence: ="&Set /A i+=1&Set "word[!i!]=%"

For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do Echo %%word[%%A]%%=!word[%%A]!
Pause
```

As you can see from the output of the penultimate line, *(added only for display purposes)*, the second word would be the value of variable `%word[2]%`.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm! There's one thing: it outputs "Environment variable word[ not defined", do you know how you can remove that? EDIT: Nevermind, fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

try this.With `for /f` you can split strings by delimiter (default ones are `=`,`<space>`,`<tab>`,`;`,`,`). So in the snippet bellow the default delimiters will act as space.

```
set /p "variableA=Enter a Sentence: "
for /f "tokens=2" %%# in ("%variableA%") set "second_word=%%~#"
echo "%second_word%"
```