# Batch file crashes after if statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a linux like terminal with batch. I don't know what's wrong with the code.
It crashes after

`Set "word[!i!]=%cmd: ="&Set /A i+=1&Set "word[!i!]=%"
echo %word[1]%
if "%word[1]%==ls" dir`.

Here's my code:

```
@Echo on
pushd C:\
Set "cmd="
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set word[') Do Set "%%A="
set "UserAccount=%username%"
cls
:Loop
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P "cmd=%UserAccount%@%UserAccount%~%cd%$ "
If Not Defined cmd EndLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & GoTo Loop
Set "i=1"
Set "word[!i!]=%cmd: ="&Set /A i+=1&Set "word[!i!]=%"
echo %word[1]%

if "%word[1]%==ls" dir
if "%word[1]%==cd" goto cd
if "%word[1]%==cd .."  cd..
if "%word[1]%==cd ." cd.
GoTo Loop
:cd
if Not Defined %word[2]% echo %cd% & GoTo Loop
cd %word[2]%

EndLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
goto Loop
```

Comment: K-Pop, there is too much wrong with your script for a proper fix. Your entire approach needs a total rethink. I have seen many questions where people are trying to use a cmd.exe batch script to write a non cmd.exe like console session, which is behaves *nix like but isn't. _I don't believe it is a reasonable or worthwhile pursuit_.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've coded

```
Set "word[!i!]=%cmd: ="&Set /A i+=1&Set "word[!i!]=%"
```

where you intended

```
Set "word[!i!]=%cmd: =%"&Set /A i+=1&Set "word[!i!]="
```

You'd then need to fix

```
if "%word[1]%==ls" dir
```

to

```
if /i "%word[1]%"=="ls" dir
```

(where the `/i` has been inserted to make the comparison case-insensitive)

I'd also avoid using `cmd` as a variable-name since `cmd.exe` is the command-processor itself.

Also, be aware that `setlocal` establishes a copy of the current environment which is released by an `endlocal`. As your code currently stands your `setlocals` are not balanced by endlocals` so you have an ever-accumulating nested environment arrangement - and the nesting level is limited.

Answer (score 1):

As well as completely overhauling your  `SetLocal/EndLocal` expressions...

Change:

```bat
if "%word[1]%==ls"
```

to

```bat
If /I "%word[1]%"=="ls"
```

Also change:

```bat
if "%word[1]%==cd"
```

to

```bat
If /I "%word[1]%"=="cd"
```

These two are not possible because each are two words, where `%word[1]%` is just `cd`

```bat
if "%word[1]%==cd .." 
if "%word[1]%==cd ."
```

Also change:

```bat
if Not Defined %word[2]%
```

to

```bat
If Not Defined word[2]
```

Also, I told you when I gave you [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943873/6738015) for setting your words, that it depended on your sentences. If you are expecting that entering commands and having the special characters and syntax recognized as individual words with that code then your likely to be disappointed.